# parallel libstdc++ mode not using parallel for_each algorithm for iterators

Tags: c++, stl, parallel-processing, libstdc++, c++17

I'm working on a parallel STL implementation of the Barnes-Hut-Algorithm.

For performance issues I wanted to try the parallel mode of some algorithms from the libstdc++
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html

This extension will also come with the new C++17 standard.

To calculate the effective acceleration for each body, I use the `for_each` algorithm from the namespace `__gnu_parallel`. To use the sequential algorithm, you can replace it by `std`.

To compile the program I use g++ with version 5.4.0 and call it by `g++-5 -fopenmp -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++1z -c -o BarnesHutCPU.o BarnesHutCPU.cpp`

For the parallel algorithms OpenMP is used. This is the reason for `-fopenmp`.

However, the time for the sequential and the parallel use of `for_each` is nearly the same. And when you call `omp_get_num_threads()` in the `for_each` loop, you get the reason that only one thread is used for the complete loop.

So my question is: Why is the algorithm not executed in parallel and what do I have to to to get a parallel execution?
 I also tried it with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./BarnesHutCPU`.

I don't want to use a normal `for` loop, because I have to use the STL algorithms. (One reason is, I want to use Thrust later)

This is the important code part with `N=750`:

```
void calcAcc()
{
    double theta = 0.5; 
    __gnu_parallel::for_each(counting_iterator<int>(0), counting_iterator<int>(N), [&](const int &i){
        ...
    }
}
```

`counting_iterator<T>` is from `boost::counting_iterator<T>`

Greetings
Tommekk

Comment: Try to add [`-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_using.html). Does your hardware actually have hardware parallelism you are asking for?

Comment: Thank you, sadly the flag did not change anything. I have 4 CPU cores and  `lscpu` in terminal says that, too.

Comment: Why `-O0` while comparing performance? Enable optimizations if you want realistic performance numbers.

Comment: I use this, because I had problems during debugging. However, using -O3 will decrease the run time, but then the sequential execution time will be even lower than for the parallel execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the reason was the -O0 flag. With -O3 it uses my 4 CPUs, which I can also see in the system monitor. At first I didn't see any effects, because my N was to small.

Thanks for your help!